# Autobuild a .NET 4.5 project when I build a .NET 4.0 project? It does NOT need to be referenced

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# project that builds with .NET 4.0 that has a soft/indirect dependency (through reflection) on a project that builds with .NET 4.5.

I'm trying to figure out the entry in `my40project.csproj` that will build `my45project.csproj` when I build `my40project.csproj`.  I do *not* need to reference the resulting DLL in the 4.0 project at all, though.

I have the following entry in `my40project.csproj`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(RootDir)\path\to\project\my45project.csproj">
  <Project>{some guid}</Project>
  <Name>my45project</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

However, this yields the following error message:

```
"D:\path\to\project\my40project.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->
  error SCP3000: A non-baseline warning (MSB3274) was encountered: The primary reference "my45project.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

Does anyone know how I might resolve this?  I apologize if this is a duplicate; the questions found when searching involved directly using the resulting .NET 4.5 DLL in the 4.0 project, which I don't need to do (I *only* need it to be built)

Thanks!

Comment: don't reference that project at all, just copy the output dll for reflection

Comment: you can't reference lower version to higher version, but can do vice-versa.  As, forward compatibility is not supported in many systems but backward compatibility is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530915/can-my-project-reference-an-assembly-targeting-a-lower-version-of-net-framework

Comment: @Steve I need to make sure that anytime someone in my big company builds the .NET 4.0 project, the 4.5 project is also built.  It doesn't have to be as a reference.  Maybe there's some sort of chain or prebuild directive?

Comment: @MuhammadImran I think you're misunderstanding what I'm trying to do.  I _don't_ need a direct reference (which is impossible).  I just need a prebuild event of sorts.

Comment: You could try using a MSBuild command for your 4.5 project run as a post build command on 4.0 project.

Answer (score 0):

Since the project does not have to be directly referenced, you have the option of using Post Build event to copy the dll. Basically you keep both projects in one solution (don't reference each other), and you config the Post Build event of the 4.5 project to include something like

```
copy /Y "source.dll" "destination"
```

this will make sure that the dll which your 4.0 project is going to be using is always the latest version after each full solution build.

Edit:
solution file

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
>
> ## Visual Studio 14 VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0   MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
>
> Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Test", "Test\Test.csproj", "{F6B2FFFE-AEBD-4D47-99F6-B4EFD200E50A}"
>   EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "test2", "test2\test2.csproj",
>   "{AD7D893B-7113-4E96-8CC1-0321E576B2A2}"
>   EndProject

project 1 target:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

project 2 target:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and build solution

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>  Test -> ------\Test.exe
>   2>  test2 -> ------\test2.exe
>   ========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Copying the DLL isn't the issue (I know how to do that), but triggering a prebuild event to build the 4.5 project before or starts to build the 4.0 project

Comment: @Benjin if you include the project in the same solution, it will get built when you perform a solution build

Comment: Can you post an example?  A standard project reference (like the one in the post) will attempt to compile it (good) but see that the reference is .NET 4.5 instead of <= 4.0 and therefore fail (bad).

Comment: @Benjin since you only need the dll for reflection, you do not need to reference the second project at all as I mentioned above. All you need to do is include both projects in one solution and perform a solution build. example included

Comment: unfortunately, our build system doesn't use solution files.  Temporary solution files are generated on the fly when you open a project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the build order won't be deterministic using this approach; i.e you can't guarantee the .NET 4.5 binary will be built before the .NET 4 build event.

Comment: @SteveChapman Since OP only need it for reflection, build order doesn't really matter