# Do we need to migrate .NET assembly to use in Windows application which migrated to .NET 4.8 framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, .net-4.8

We want to migrate Windows application to Microsoft .NET 4.8 Framework and it uses assembly which running against .NET 4.5. Since it is used by multiple applications, we installed it into the global assembly cache.

So my questions is, do we need to migrate that assembly to .NET 4.8 as well in order for it to work with the migrated Windows application?

Comment: you're asking if you need to upgrade the referenced projects also when upgrading your application to .net 4.8, right?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530915/can-my-project-reference-an-assembly-targeting-a-lower-version-of-net-framework?

Comment: Yes @MakePeaceGreatAgain to answer your first comment.

Comment: No.  You only set the *minimum* version of .NET that the user needs to have installed.  net48 has no trouble executing code in assemblies of earlier 4.x versions.  You'll enable a few bug fixes made between 4.5 and 4.8 but they are very obscure.

Answer (score 1):

If the package compiles fine with .NET 4.8, there is no need for the upgrade. Else an upgrade would be needed provided the new package is available